# How to empty my destination table before inserting new records in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, relational-database

I use SSIS to generate and transform new data for later use in a new system. I have a problem every time I run my SSIS Package, it keeps inserting new records to my destination tables.

How can I empty my destination table (/OLE DB Destination) first and then inserting the newly generated records?

Currently the workaround for this problem is performing a `delete from DestTable` before running my package.

Comment: Put your delete statement in an `Execute SQL Task`. Then make it the first component of your flow.

Comment: It could be the solution, you can give it as answer.

Comment: Don't do that - merge the table. Otherwise when your job fails you'll be left with an empty table and other things will break.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Put your delete statement in an `Execute SQL Task`. Then make it the first component of your flow. The component looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE <name>` is *much* better for tables with many rows. Not only will it be faster, it won't fill up the transaction log. I've had a production database server crash due to a transaction log filling up the disk after a `DELETE FROM` command was executed on a table with 30 million rows.

Answer (score 36):

Create an Execute SQL task.   Have it run first.  For the sqlstatment do.

```
Truncate table DestTable
```

Using truncate table is better then using delete as it ignores all the indexes and just removes everything.

For a little background info.  I will try and explain why you should use truncate table instead of delete table.   Delete table is a row based operation this means that each row is deleted.   Truncate table is a data page operation the entire data page is delocated.   If you have a table with a million rows it will be much faster to truncate the table then it would be to use a delete table statment.

Comment: you sure about this ?

Comment: Its how i do it.  Im sure there are a lot of diffrent ways of removeing data from stageing tables before reloading new information.   Everyone has there own way of doing things.

Comment: +1 - I really don't care which one is better. But the explanation you gave about the speed is important. But I got the answer for my problem that's what is important. You can ask a question about this [has to be according to the Stack Overflow rules]

Answer (score 7):

One caveat about using Truncate table, it does run better for the reasons stated.  However it also requires additional privileges for your SSIS System account.
You should be sure that those are available to you in Production, otherwise you will have to use Delete.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177570.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this

```
truncate table table_name
```

this empties the table

Comment: you can put this in exe-sql task,`delete from table` and `truncate table` does the same thing !!

Comment: They really don't. They are *similar*, but nevertheless, different. Heres a link http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1080/deleting-data-in-sql-server-with-truncate-vs-delete-commands/

Comment: thanks for **[link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1080/deleting-data-in-sql-server-with-truncate-vs-delete-commands/)**

Comment: Truncate table and delete table are not the same thing.  They may do the same thing but that doesnt mean they are the same.   http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/05/09/the-difference-in-truncate-and-delete-in-sql-server/   Truncate table is faster and if you want to delete everthing in the table anyway why not do whats fastest.

Comment: i know they does same stuff but they are quite different !!