# How to clear a destination table when importing new data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I've just begun using SSIS and I've been trying to set up a data flow where I import data from a CSV file into a table on one of the servers.

I can read from the flat file (CSV) and insert it into SQL server OK, but I need to add an extra step and I can't figure out how: I want to delete all records from the table before I insert the new values.

Does anyone know how to help? Thanks!

Comment: That helps! I also found this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237329/how-to-empty-my-destination-table-before-inserting-new-records-in-ssis) that really helped.

Comment: No worries at all @GrymByrd. Sometimes it's hard to find the right question while searching, so don't view the closure as a bad thing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use TRUNCATE

> Removes all rows from a table or specified partitions of a table

```
  TRUNCATE TABLE yourdb.yourschema.your_destination_table;
```

before staring a new importing session

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in these two previous posts:

[How to empty my destination table before inserting new records in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237329/how-to-empty-my-destination-table-before-inserting-new-records-in-ssis)

[How to delete large data of table in SQL without log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213299/how-to-delete-large-data-of-table-in-sql-without-log)

Basically, set up a SQL Task that runs the command "TRUNCATE TABLE your.table" and then connect it to your Data Flow task.